# VLC video doesn't play in main window

Tags: vlc

After upgrading to 2.2.1, VLC videos plays in a separate window, but I want the controls to be in the same window as the video (just the way it was before I upgraded).

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep they changed it.

Now there is no more within the Video screen popup controls, unless you are in full screen mode.

Option is to use the media keys on your keyboard, or right click to control it.

Not sure I like the change.

Comment: Ah I see. Ya, so not used looking for the control's window when I needed to scrub it. Hopefully they'll put it back.

Comment: I got so used to the popup controls, now I have to learn all over again. I hate when they do that, without telling, so you can decide to do the upgrade or not, since once upgraded, there is no way back :(

Answer (score -2):

don't ask me how cos i really hardly understand these things, but i fiddled about for a bit and suddenly it worked. maybe this screensave[image] can help